# Как реализовать цикл для заполнения таблицы QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Столкнулся с затруднением в процессе написания кода. После того как объединил некоторые ячейки с помощью метода .setSpan для QTableWidget не могу сообразить каким образом реализовать цикл для заполнения этой таблицы. (на снимке не видно, но в стб.3 так же есть разделённые на 3 строки и не разделённые)
[image: Таким образом выглядит моя таблица]

Вот фрагмент кода касающийся заполнения таблицы(написан был до того как пришлось объединять ячейки:

```
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []

for list_dict in json_table.values():
    for key_value in list_dict: 
        keys = key_value.keys()
        value = key_value.values()
        for key_item in keys:
            column1.append(key_item)        #значения для 1 столбца
        for value_item in value:
            column2.append(value_item[0])   #значения 2 столбца
            column3.append(value_item[1:])  #списки со значениями для 3 столбца
for row in range(table.rowCount()):
    c = (0,1,3,4)
    for col in c:
        table.setSpan(row%60,col,2,1)

for row in range(table.rowCount()):                 
    column_pop = column1.pop(0)
    table.setCellWidget(row%60,0,QPushButton(QIcon(":"+ column_pop),''))
    if column_pop == "Fish.webp":   
        ik = QTableWidgetItem()
        ik2 = ik.setIcon(QIcon(":Portrait_Farmer"))
        table.setItem(row%60,2, ik2)                    
    widget = QTableWidgetItem(column2.pop(0))   
    widget.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
    table.setItem(row%60,1,widget)                  
    a = column3.pop(0)
    b = '\n'.join(a)                    
    widget = QTableWidgetItem(b)
    widget.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
    table.setItem(row%60,2,widget)
```

Таким образом, могу предположить что цикл должен выглядеть примерно в таком порядке: берется длинна взятого элемента из списка column3 далее через условие if циклом элементы этого взятого списка вставляются в таблицу. Условие if для столбцов 1,2,4,5;что бы определить количество объединения ячеек. Но тут я и не могу сообразить, каким образом это реализовать, ведь каждый раз когда элемент списка column3 будет доставаться длинна будет изменяться.
Я уже бросил идею заполнить всю таблицу одной функцией, **но может быть есть возможность вставлять метод через то количество строк которое стоит в условии? При этом проверять длину предыдущего списка что бы на это количество строк опуститься вниз**

**Или все намного проще и есть возможность вставлять в Item QTableWidget несколько иконок?**
(В таком случае я могу избежать объединения ячеек и как следствие проблемы с циклами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо разместить в ячейке таблицы сложный виджет, совершенно не обязательно для этого разбивать ячейки. Компонуйте все необходимые элементы в один виджет (к примеру `QFrame`) и вставляйте его. Небольшой пример

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QFrame, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def createCellWidget(self, pix, text, btn):
        layout = QGridLayout()
        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setLayout(layout)
        picture = QLabel()
        picture.setPixmap(pix)
        layout.addWidget(picture, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(text), 0, 1)
        button = QPushButton(btn)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda x: QMessageBox.information(self, 'clicked', 'button clicked'))
        layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)
        return frame

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        table = QTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setRowCount(10)
        table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        for i in range(0, 10):
            pixmap = QPixmap('/home/arise/PyCharm/bin/pycharm.png').scaled(50, 50)
            widget = self.createCellWidget(pixmap, f'hello here\ntext_{i}_0', f'button{i}_0')
            table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(f'line_{i}'))
            table.setCellWidget(i, 1, widget)

        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!